# speeding up processing on sheets add-on

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am making an add on that processes content from a Google Sheets doc and returns it (for now) to new sheet in the spreadsheet. The first iteration works but is deadly slow. I think it's because it processes the data sheet one line at a time. So I'm rewriting it to ingest all the data and then process the array it lives in.

Problem is the amount of data appears to be prohibitive. I can see this in Logger output, in execution transcript, and in stackdriver logging; it gets to about line 35 (11 columns) before it runs out of room.

here is the original version (takes an insane amount of time):
'''
var compareDate = selDate;

```
var bulletin = ss.getSheetByName(reportSheetName);
var responses = ss.getSheetByName("Calendar");

var lastRow = responses.getLastRow(); //get last row of data sheet
var lastBull = bulletin.getLastRow();  //get last row of bulletin sheet
var nextBullRow = lastBull+1;
var nextBullItem = bulletin.getRange(nextBullRow,1);

for(var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
  var row = responses.getRange(i, 1, 1, 11).getValues();

  var dateA = new Date((row[0][4]).valueOf());
  var eventType = row[0][0].valueOf();
  var eventCalDate = new Date(row[0][4].valueOf());
  var eventEvent = row[0][3].valueOf();
  var eventOpp = row[0][7].valueOf();
  var eventLocation = row[0][8].valueOf();

  var eventMonth = eventCalDate.getMonth();
  var eventDate = eventCalDate.getDate();
  var eventYear = eventCalDate.getYear();
  var eventShortDate = eventMonth+"/"+eventDate+"/"+eventYear;

  var start = new Date(thisWeekSt);
  var end = new Date(thisWeekEnd);


  /*var masterDate = new Date(compareDate).valueOf();
  var thisCat = row[0][3];
  var bullItem = row[0][4]; */
  var dateMatch = false;
  if(dateA > start && dateA < end) {
  dateMatch=true;  

    bulletin.getRange(nextBullRow,1,nextBullRow,6).setFontWeight("normal");

  bulletin.getRange(nextBullRow,typeCol).setValue(eventType);
  bulletin.getRange(nextBullRow,dateCol).setValue(eventShortDate);
  bulletin.getRange(nextBullRow,timeCol).setValue(eventType);
  bulletin.getRange(nextBullRow,eventCol).setValue(eventEvent);
  bulletin.getRange(nextBullRow,oppCol).setValue(eventOpp);
  bulletin.getRange(nextBullRow,locCol).setValue(eventLocation);
  nextBullRow++;

  Logger.log(bulletin.getRange(nextBullRow-1,6).getValue());

  if(bulletin.getRange(nextBullRow-1,6).getValue()=="Hollister") {
    bulletin.getRange(nextBullRow-1,1,nextBullRow-1,6).setFontWeight("bold");
    Logger.log("boop!");
  }
```

'''

And here's the new version, which doesn't have the digital appetite for all the data;
'''
    var compareDate = selDate;

```
var bulletin = ss.getSheetByName(reportSheetName);
var responses = ss.getSheetByName("Calendar");

var lastRow = responses.getLastRow(); //get last row of data sheet
var lastBull = bulletin.getLastRow();  //get last row of bulletin sheet
var nextBullRow = lastBull+1;
var nextBullItem = bulletin.getRange(nextBullRow,1);

var allData = responses.getRange(2, 1, responses.getLastRow(), 11).getValues();  


for(var i = 2; i <= allData.getLastRow(); i++) {
  var row = allData.getRange(i, 1, 1, 11).getValues();
  Logger.log(row);
```

'''

Let me know if you want the whole function, I'll edit.

The question is: how can I speed data processing from the sluggish pace it is at currently. (Thanks Cooper!)

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2):

In your for loop you are calling getValues each iteration of your loop which looks like the issue. You've already got the data in your call above.

Try:

```js
for(var i = 0; i <= allData.getLastRow(); i++) {
  var row = allData[i];
  Logger.log(row);
```

Comment: Thanks Boomer: I just tried your solution (which looks solid to me) but it still chokes at the amount of data it captures.

Comment: How many rows of data are you looping through and what are you doing with it? You can come up with a bit of a hack if you don't need it all to happen quickly. Set a Counter cell with an initial value of the row you want to start your loop with and the read that and update it with the counter value each loop. It's less efficient because it calls .getValue() and .setValue() each loop but if you call the function every x minutes it will pick up where it left off. 

You could get and set value every nth loop if you wanted to do this quicker but it does make it a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks Boomer. The content is an events schedule for the school where I teach. I just want to have this function cough up the events for a given week or month or event type. Likely it would help if I have a separate tab/sheet for each athletic season to cut down on the amount of data it has to crunch. Currently there are about 300 lines of data 12 columns wide. If I delete old stuff from Fall season I drops by half. It works currently but is pretty slow, taking about 30 seconds to get the job done by processing one line at a time. Thanks for putting your thinker behind this.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today. My solution was to duplicate the sheet and then work on the copy:

```
sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
copy=sheet.duplicateActiveSheet()
```

after duplicating, the copy is the active sheet, so you can directly work on it, e.g. delete rows like that:

```
sheet.deleteRows(1,2)
```